# Why are memory addresses in pointers important

Tags: c++, pointers

I personally believe I have a firm grasp of pointers, but let's say

```
int* pMyPointer;
int number = 1000;
pMyPointer = &number;
cout << pMyPointer << endl;
```

pMyPointer might return a memory address of 0037FBB0, but why does that matter? How can this be useful while programming?

Comment: Because when I go out I need to know where are the keys. A pointer is akin to know where things are (i.e. when I come back I can crash out)

Comment: Because that's what a pointer contains. Not a real question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Object identity**.

If you have two pointers or references, how can you tell if using one could affect the other?  Simply printing the current value of all the data members won't tell you if they are the same object or clones/copies.

So when you're debugging, you become very interested in whether the addresses stored in different pointers are the same, which requires you to inspect those address values.

Comment: +1, But object identity could be abstracted away from the address, which could then be accessible from the debugger only. I think OP is asking why it matters to have access to the specific address in a c++ program. It could be seen as an implementation detail. I think we're so used to it that it has become natural.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Not could be -- has been.  Pointer values are not memory addresses (in user-mode code), they are just object ID values able to find the memory, with the help of page tables and the memory management unit.  And even debuggers do not show you the actual memory address.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! And pardon me for asking an apparently stupid question :/

Answer (score 0):

This is a very important information in static memory management.
In userspace application development, this information might be irrelevant to the most developers, but they are very important for the low-level developer. Remember, programming languages with static memory manager will *always* be lower level languages.

This also the main point in how pointers work. They store memory addresses to where they point.
You can also create a pointer like this: `int *mptr = (int*)0x13371234;`. This creates a pointer which points to the `int` at `0x13371234`.

It also gives you information about where your stuff in stored, and this can also be used to determine the location of the stack, if for any reason inline assembly is not allowed. If you use malloc, then it is generally not a must-need information.

Answer (score 0):

A typical use is to create linked data structures like lists and trees.

For example, in a binary tree each node contains a pointer to its two children.

[image]

As far as the pointer goes, the actual value only *rarely* means much in itself. It's usually used as a "magic cookie" -- an essentially "magic" value gives you access to some particular variable. In a typical case you save an address into a pointer, then dereference the pointer to get to the item at that address, without ever examining (or even caring about) the value of the pointer itself.

There are a few exceptions to this general rule though. For one example, some memory allocators use the address of a block to track not only the location of the block, but also the block's size. By starting with a block aligned to a large boundary, and always splitting blocks by powers of 2, the whole address tells the location of the block, and the lower bits of the address tell the size of the block that must have been allocated to get to that address.

The latter are definitely the exceptions though. The *typical* case is that the value of the pointer means nothing beyond giving access to the item at that address.

Comment: This explains why pointers are important and useful, but I don't think that's what the question was asking about.